# How to get the first node prior to the current node that contains text using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a node that contains the text `'The f'`:

```
<w:r w:rsidR="00BC78BF">
  <w:t>e takes out his phone and calls a friend.</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00CB49B6">
  <w:t xml:space="preserve"/>
</w:r>
<w:ins w:author="Mitchell Gould" w:date="2016-11-14T14:23:00Z" w:id="8">
  <w:r w:rsidR="00BC7F15">
    <w:t>The f</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:ins>
```

I want to get the first occurrence of text that exists before this text node.

I tried using:

```
 node.previous_element.text
 => " "
```

and

```
previous_node = node.xpath('preceding-sibling::w:r').last
=> " "
```

This is because sometimes the `previous_element` is just a space as shown above, and it is possible that there could be many of these elements that are just spaces.

How can I get the first prior sibling that contains text?

Comment: What do you expect to receive? “e takes out his phone and calls a friend.”? What have you tried _in code_?

Comment: I updated my question to show what I have tried.  Yes I would like to get "“e takes out his phone and calls a friend.”

Comment: Get a collection of `w:t` nodes and iterate it one step backward to retrieve the _previous `w:t` element_. Or go with recursive `previous_element` unless it’s `text` property is not empty.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a way to do this that used some more sophisticated search parameters of Nokogiri

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<xml>
  <r>
    <t>e takes out his phone and calls a friend.</t>
  </r>
  <r>
    <t/>
  </r>
  <ins>
    <r>
      <t>The f</t>
    </r>
  </ins>
</xml>
EOT

doc.search('//text()').map { |t| t.text.strip }.reject(&:empty?)
# => ["e takes out his phone and calls a friend.", "The f"]
```

Then it becomes a question of identifying the element prior to `"The f"` which I'll leave as a task for you. It isn't hard but, in a big document, could definitely affect code performance.

`//text()` is the XPath way to find all the text nodes in a document. `//` means "search from the top down" basically. A text node isn't just things like "The f", it can also be the new-line following a closing tag in a pretty-printed XML file.

`text.strip` followed by `reject` is done to remove any XML formatting between nodes, spaces and empty lines.